# How to generify a method when T can be multiple new () Types?

Tags: c#, generics, model

Currently trying to generefify a method I have. Don't know much about generics so sorry if it seems dumb...

The current method I have :

```
public SimpleGenericModel GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode(FicheArticleViewModel model, string alias) 
        {
            var listeItems = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias);
            var result = new SimpleGenericModel();

            if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return result;

            foreach (var item in listeItems)
            {
                result.Id = item.Id.ToString();
                result.Nom = item.Name;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

thing is, now the SimpleGenericModel can also be a RegionModel and a SecteurDActiviteModel...

I tried this :

```
 public T GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T> (FicheArticleViewModel model, string alias) where T: new()
        {
            var listeItems = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias);

            var result = new T();

            //if (typeof(T) == typeof(SimpleGenericModel))
            //{
            //    result = new SimpleGenericModel();
            //}
            //else if (typeof(T) == typeof(RegionViewModel))
            //{
            //    result = new RegionViewModel();

            //}
            //else if (typeof(T) == typeof(SecteurDActiviteViewModel))
            //{
            //    result = new SecteurDActiviteViewModel();
            //}

            if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return result;

            foreach (var item in listeItems)
            {
                result.Id = item.Id.ToString();
                result.Nom = item.Name;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but i'm a bit lost in it...
Any help would be appreciated... :)

Comment: Do all of the types that you need to instantiate also have an `Id` and `Name` property? Is there an interface for those properties?

Comment: Your `foreach` loop looks pretty suspicious. You set two property values on the same object multiple times, so the last iteration wins.

Comment: agree with @dymanoid, does not make sense get a list a assign to the same object over and over the same properties, for me this should looks like the method should return IEnumerable<T> instead a single T, and instead of having var result = new T() should be IEnumerable<T> result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `RegionModel` & `SecteurDActiviteModel` will share the `Id` & `Nom` properties, I would suggest you create an `ISomeInterface` and implement it on your types, `RegionModel : ISomeInterface`. It is not necessary to return the actual type like you are doing - `result = new SimpleGenericModel();` - the type will be known at compile time by the `T` you pass to the method.

With the new interface you can constraint the method even more like this:

```
public T GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T> (FicheArticleViewModel model, string alias) where T: new(), ISomeInterface,
```

So your structure should looks like this:

```
public T GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T>(string model, string alias) where T : ISomeInterface, new()
{
    var listeItems = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias);
    var result = new T();
    if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return result;
    foreach (var item in listeItems)
    {
        result.Id = item.Id.ToString();
        result.Nom = item.Name;
    }
    return result;
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Nom { get; set; }
}

public class RegionModel : ISomeInterface
{
    //Your implementation goes here
}

public class SecteurDActiviteModel : ISomeInterface
{
    //Your implementation goes here
}
```

One more thing : you are mapping to the same object the same properties over and over, which does not make sense, if what you want is to get a collection of `T` from the `listeItems`. You should change your code like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T>(string model, string alias) where T : ISomeInterface, new()
{
    var listeItems = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias);   
    if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return listeItems.Select(i => new T 
    {
        Id = i.Id.ToString(),
        Nom = i.Name,
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

If your listeItems will have a single value the just do a `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` to get the item and map, like this:

```
public T GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T>(string model, string alias) where T : ISomeInterface, new()
{
    var listeItem = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias).FirstOrDefault();   
    if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return new T();

    if (listeItem == null)
    {
        return new T();
    }

    return new T
    {
        Id = listeItem.Id.ToString(),
        Nom = item.Name
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! it's exactly what I needed:) For the "one more thing" thing : I don't want a list because I know there will be only one result. It's just that i have to iterate because Umbraco multinodetreepicker returns a list and that's what I was told to use...

Comment: if you are going to get a single result then the foreach is no needed and you can use a [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) / [SingleOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) from Linq to get the item and map the properties directly.

Comment: It works just fine, and it's way more neet that what I was doing... thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you define an interface:

```
interface INomAndId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Nom  { get; set; }
}
```

And implement it in your models:

```
class SimpleGenericModel : INomAndId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}

class RegionViewModel : INomAndId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}

class SecteurDActiviteViewModel : INomAndId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}

class FicheArticleViewModel : INomAndId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the interface as a constraint:

```
where T: INomAndId, new()
```

Which will allow you to populate the new object:

```
public T GetSimpleModelFromMultiNode<T> (FicheArticleViewModel model, string alias) where T: INomAndId, new()
{
    var listeItems = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(alias);
    var result = new T();
    if (!CurrentPage.HasValue(alias)) return result;
    foreach (var item in listeItems)
    {
        result.Id = item.Id.ToString();
        result.Nom = item.Name;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) since Unnamed wrote about the Interface thing too and your ideas both link, i'll go for this :)